# Has Revelation 14:9 changed from bibles printed over 40 years ago?

Tags: bible-translation, revelation

I used to have a nice picture bible growing up and I read and re-read Revelations growing up as a kid. I recently heard that verse but it's not as I remember it. Did it always say "or in the hand?" or just forehead?

Comment: Even the KJV has hand: http://biblehub.com/revelation/14-9.htm

Comment: @Jeffrey Allan Backowski II - Which translation was your picture bible? It may have just been a shortened or simplified version of a full translation, in which case it may have skipped over certain words and details.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). That particular verse has always had "or in the hand," as you can see in the listing of Bible translations of that verse [here](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Revelation%2014:9). However, some other verses in Revelation have only "forehead," as you can see in these search results for "forehead" in Revelation [here](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=KJV&quicksearch=forehead&startnumber=13). Perhaps you were thinking of one of those other verses.

Comment: Notably, there is [a lot of forehead-marking going on in Revelation](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Rev%207%3A3%3B%209%3A4%3B%2013%3A16%3B%2014%3A1%2C%209%3B%2017%3A5%3B%2020%3A4%3B%2022%3A4&version=SBLGNT;ESV), and a minority of these mentions includes an alternative  "on the hand". Is it possible that you may be remembering one of the others?

Answer (score 6):

BibleGateway.com has about [fifty English translations of this verse](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Revelation%2014:9), and they all include *hand*.

This includes older translations like the KJV, RSV, and The Living Bible (1971).  Of course, Bible Gateway is not exhaustive, so it's possible that you had a children's Bible using a different translation or paraphrase.

That said, it's clear that the inclusion of *hand* in this passage is not a recent development.